# Funcion breadthfirst en Ocaml que calcule el recorrido por niveles de un arbol binario

Tags: programación-funcional

necesito una función para obtener el recorrido por niveles de un árbol binario. El árbol sería con este tipo:

```
type 'a bin_tree = Empty | Node of 'a * 'a bin_tree * 'a bin_tree;;
```

Lo único que tengo es una función para recorrer un árbol normal:

```
let rec breadth_first = function
    Gt (x, []) -> [x] 
   | Gt (x, (Gt (y, t2))::t1) -> x :: breadth_first (Gt (y, t1@t2));;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let breath_first tree =
   let rec recorrido acum = function
      [] -> List.rev acum
      |Empty::t -> recorrido acum t
      |Node (x, Empty, Empty)::t -> recorrido (x::acum) t
      |Node (x, r, Empty)::t
      |Node (x, Empty, r)::t -> recorrido (x::acum) (List.append t [r])
      |Node (x, r, e)::t -> recorrido (x::acum) (List.append t [r; e])
   in recorrido [] [tree];;
```